# Elasticsearch query to return part of words searched for

Tags: elasticsearch, search

I would like to know how I can return "thanks" or "thanking" if I search for "thank"
Currently I have a multi-match query which returns only occurrences of "thank" like "thank you" but not "thanksgiving" or "thanks". I am using ElasticSearch 7.9.1

```
query: {
                bool: {
                    must: [
                        {match: {accountId}},
                        {
                            multi_match: {
                                query: "thank",
                                type: "most_fields",
                                fields: ["text", "address", "description", "notes", "name"],
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    filter: {match: {type: "personaldetails"}}
                }
            },
```

Also is it possible to combine the multimatch query with a queryString on one of the fields (say description, where I would do a querystring search only on description and a phrase match on other fields)

```
    {   "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "(new york city) OR (big apple)",
          "default_field": "content"
        }   
       } 
     }
```

Any input is appreciated.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

> You can use [edge_ngrma tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html) that first breaks text down into
> words whenever it encounters one of a list of specified characters,
> then it emits N-grams of each word where the start of the N-gram is
> anchored to the beginning of the word.

Adding a working example with index data, mapping, search query, and search result

**Index Mapping:**

```
    {
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_tokenizer": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": 5,
          "max_gram": 20,
          "token_chars": [
            "letter",
            "digit"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "max_ngram_diff": 50
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "notes": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
        "search_analyzer": "standard"    // note this
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{
    "notes":"thank"
}
{
    "notes":"thank you"
}
{
    "notes":"thanks"
}
{
    "notes":"thanksgiving"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match" : {
      "query":    "thank", 
      "fields": [ "notes", "name" ] 
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "65511630",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.1448707,
        "_source": {
          "notes": "thank"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "65511630",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 0.1448707,
        "_source": {
          "notes": "thank you"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "65511630",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.12199639,
        "_source": {
          "notes": "thanks"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "65511630",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "4",
        "_score": 0.06264679,
        "_source": {
          "notes": "thanksgiving"
        }
      }
    ]
```

**To combine multi-match query with query string, use the below query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "multi_match": {
          "query": "thank",
          "fields": [
            "notes",
            "name"
          ]
        }
      },
      "should": {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "(new york city) OR (big apple)",
          "default_field": "content"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @user14262559 did you get a chance to go through the answer, looking forward to get feedback from you 

Comment: sorry about the delay. was sick and could not try this so far. Will be trying this today.

Comment: @user14262559 no worries  Get well, soon!

Comment: Sorry about the delay in responding. This works finding partial words but the issue I am seeing is with case sensitivity. For instance typing in "new" no longer get "New York" I found a stackoverflowing post with the detail that adding customer mappers will cause issues with case insensitivity. Can you please let me know if there is a workaround here.

Comment: I am looking for case insensitive normally except when within quotes

Comment: @user14262559 in the question you mentioned that you also want to return **"thanksgiving" or "thanks"**, when you are searching for `"thanks"`. I think this part of the question is solved by the query I gave above. I didn't get this part of your comment **For instance typing in "new" no longer get "New York"**. Can you please explain this ?

Comment: I do see thanks  and thanksgiving returned when I search for thanks but if I have "Thanks" it is not being returned. Without custom mapping elasticsearch returns were case insensitive.

Comment: sorry about the confusion with examples of "new" and "New York". Basically the search are now case sensitive

Comment: @user14262559 so you want searches to be case insensitive?

Comment: @user14262559 If you want case insensitive searches, then you need to add `search_analyzer` in your index mapping settings. Please go through my updated index mapping, and let me know if this resolves your issue ?

Comment: @user14262559 did you get a chance to go through the updated index mapping ?

Comment: the combination does not work. So if I search for thanks or Thanks, "thank" is returned at all. I was reviewing the Elastic search docs and if it is not specified it defaults to standard analyzer (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/analysis-standard-analyzer.html).

Comment: Right now I have 

    "text": { 
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
        "search_analyzer": "standard"
      },

Comment: I searched for "Thank" here and this was my output 

    "text" : "Thank you, guys, really great questions. And thank you, Mairin for being so vulnerable and open with us and sharing your story. I think I'm certainly still inspired. And I think you've inspired a lot of people in the room here,"
          
        },
        "highlight" : {
          "text" : [
            "And <em>thank</em> you, Mairin for being so vulnerable and open with us and sharing your story."
          ]
        },

Comment: as you can see there the first "Thank" did not even get highlighted. also if I search for "Thanks" or "thanks" nothing comes back after adding the search_analyzer